# Modals verbs differences in questions

Tags: modal-verbs, questions

- Will you turn on the radio, please?
- Would you turn on the radio, please?
- May you turn on the radio, please?

What are the differences between all these way of asking a request?

Comment: On which differences are you actually interested?

Comment: I am interested in them all but anyway it seems I have to shorten them a little. I edited my post.

Comment: _May_ is used mostly with _I_ rather than _you_ and for permission _May I borrow your dictionary_ for an instance. _Would_ and _will_ are used for requests. It's the matter of function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **Will** you pass me the salt, please?

Polite, but be careful with intonation.

Stressing the words *you*, and *please* while [looking daggers at](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/look-daggers-at-sb) your interlocutor will make the request sound abrupt, and accusatory.

The words; *you*, *pass*, and *salt*, should be stressed lightly and naturally. The words *pass me* should sound as if they were linked.

> **Would** you pass me the salt, please?

If I had to *write* a polite request on paper, this is the one I would choose. I don't know exactly why, but *would* sounds more pleading to my ears, as if you're really asking someone for an act of kindness. Maybe it's Dr Seuss's  *Green Eggs and Ham* (1960) that drummed it into my head.

> **Would** you like them
>   in a house?
>   Would you like them
>   with a mouse?
>
> [...]
>
> Would you? **Could** you?
>   In a car? Eat them! Eat them!
>   Here they are.

Which brings me to *could*, which the OP forgot to add to the list

> **Could** you pass me the salt, please?

Again, very polite. There's hardly any difference between the modal verbs *could* and *would*, in terms of politeness.

Now, some very stuffy grammarian or pedant might object, and point out that  *can* refers to *ability*, and speakers should say *may I*; *yawn*, *yawn*, *yawn* ... Native speakers continually use the words *can* and *could* in favours and requests.

Finally,

> **May** you pass me the salt, please?

This is not idiomatic. It's not common and it sounds as if I am asking him or her permission to pass me the salt. This request borders on pretentious sounding, and also close to weird. Far, far better would be to ask:

> **May** I have the salt, please?

Extremely polite, it scores a straight 10 on the polite-o-meter.

Answer (score -2):

The first one is the least polite and the last one is the most polite in my opinion. Someone may have been annoyed for a while and losing patience if he asks in the first sentence's way.

Comment: *May* seems strange to me, so I'm not sure I could classify it as 'most polite' or 'least polite' personally.

Comment: @snailplane Maybe in other words, "the least formal" and "the most formal" ?